# Count across multiple fields / columns inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I use this code:

```
var mydynlist = AsDynamic(App.Data["mydynlistsource"]);

foreach(var q in mydynlist){
    ...
            <td>@q.a1</td>
            <td>@q.b1</td>
            <td>@q.b2</td>
            <td>@q.b3</td>
    ...
}
```

and it correctly replaces the values with

```
    <td>s</td>
    <td>n</td>
    <td>na/td>
    <td>s</td>
```

Each field can assume the values "s", "n" or "na". I use these 4 as examples, but there are over 50 fields.

I need to add a new row with the total number of fields with the "s" value.
I tried using this solution that works outside the loop:

```
foreach(var q in auditorias){
    ...
            <td>@q.SelectMany(i=> new string[] {i.a1, i.b1, i.b2, i.b3 })
                  .Count(i => i == "s")</td>
            <td>@q.a1</td>
            <td>@q.b1</td>
            <td>@q.b2</td>
            <td>@q.b3</td>
    ...
}
```

But this gives the error: "Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type".

Is there any way to achieve this without using an if clause for each field?

Comment: Not sure of a way directly around it without knowing underlying type of you AsDynamic method. Is it an ExpandoObject? Or otherwise why not just keep strongly typed?

Comment: @JasonW Can't really tell. It's a module (2sxc) from the DotNetNuke CMS.

Comment: There might be a reflection method you could try. Added example below in answer.

Answer (score 0):

May not be that fast, but you can use reflection to work around the `dynamic` limitations with LINQ.

```
<td>@(((Type)q.GetType()).GetProperties().Select(m => (object)m.GetValue(q)).Count(m => "s".Equals(m)))</td>
```

You could wrap it with extension method:

```
public static int GetCount(this object q, string match)
{
    var values = ((Type)q.GetType()).GetProperties()
        .Select(m => (object)m.GetValue(q))
        .Count(m => match.Equals(m));
    return values;
}
```

And then simplify your call a little bit if you need to re-use it anywhere:

```
<td>@(q as object).GetCount("s")</td>
```

This code only works for finding properties of the dynamic object. You would use the `GetFields()` method if dynamic object used fields instead of properties (or modify your extension method to union the 2 values.

You could get some performance boost by only calling the GetFields()/GetProperties() methods once, but this assumes all your dynamic values are the same structure. Otherwise, if the first dynamic object was missing attributes it did not use (such as "b2"), then other dynamic objects having that attribute would not find the "s" in the "b2" attribute.

Comment: Not sure if reflection is even supported or if new methods are possible inside the view file.

Comment: Absolutely. If you do it as an extension method, then import the namespace of the static class containing the extension method (`@using MyNamespace`)

Comment: Sorry for the lack of feedbak. I'm still learning how to implement some steps of this solution.

Comment: Hey there. Again, sorry for the delay. In your solution, where do I specify the columns/fields to be searched (a1, b1, b2, etc)?

Comment: In extension method example, it would just be the parameter.